# How to store emails for email program?

Tags: python, email

I am trying to create a fully fledged email program ala Thunderbird. What I can't figure out is how to properly store imap headers / pop messages.

Some ideas I've had so far:

- sqlite database
- mbox file
- Maildir folders

I'm mainly concerned with the speed at which I could read from / write to each format at the same time. My original idea was to create a threaded sqlite function which has one thread for writing to the db (when new messages are pulled down from the server) and one thread for reading from the database (so that messages could be displayed in the GUI.

What would be the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Why won't you just have a peek at thunderbird code?

Comment: For desktop use, the speed should not be a big problem. And properly coded, it should also be easy to switch backend later on (ie. don't sprinkle specific back-end code throughout your application, but create a class MailStorage, or something). I would probably use sqlite btw;

Comment: Interoperability with other software is more important than speed. Go with Maildir.